# Windows Service Bus Topic/Queue Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, servicebus

What is the recommended way of monitoring Windows Service Bus Subscription and Queues? I would ideally like to monitor and alert on:

-Dead letter count

-Total Message

-Messages older than a given timespan

I have looked at SCOM Packs http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35383 but it appears to monitor the Farm and Hosts etc, not individual queues or topics.

Ideally I would like a pre-build application instead of having to develop one if at all possible.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows Azure SDK 2.0 release was added "Message Browse" features

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn198643.aspx

You can use the features above to try to monitoring queue to obtain requested data.

Paolo.